# Is it okay to add a button in google ads in native view

Tags: ios, admob

I want to add a custom button to open a screen of my application in google native ads view is it okay for google ad policy because i cannot found anything related to this in policy and i am not sure to do this or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can.

Here is an example from [Google AdMob Native Ads Playbook](https://admob.google.com/home/resources/native-ads-playbook/)

[image]